# Compare value of cells

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a very simple issue (why I cant believe Iam not seeing the mistake). I want to compare a series of cells with each other. If one of them contains any value and the other doesnt, the if statement should be true (so BolPIDEqual = false). 
Easy enough but when I test it, The if Statemnt never gets true (BolPIDEqual = false) even when the test data isnt the same for both cells/ranges. For Example A1 = "1" and A2 = "" leads to non of the ifs being triggered, but the second if should trigger and set BolPIDEqual to false...

Please help me, i really dont see what Iam doing wrong...

```
For r = 1 To 5
                 If Worksheets("X").Cells(1, r).Value = "" And Worksheets("X").Cells(2, r).Value = "*?*" Then
                    BolPIDEqual = False
                ElseIf Worksheets("X").Cells(1, r).Value = "*?*" And Worksheets("X").Cells(2, r).Value = "" Then
                    BolPIDEqual = False
                End If
            Next r
```

Comment: You want like a d not =

Comment: Jesus... Thank you alot, off course you are right...

Comment: Would an `or` not do it?  `blnResult=(range a<>"" or range b<>"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest this change. If I understand your predicament correctly. I change the sheet name to Sheet1 so that I can test locally.

```
Sub testCells()

  For r = 1 To 5

                 If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, r).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, r).Value) Then
                    BolPIDEqual = False
                ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, r).Value) And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, r).Value) Then
                    BolPIDEqual = False
                End If
            Next r
   End Sub
```

One thing worth mentioning is that you still have to set `BolPIDEqual` to true when the conditions is actually met.
Hope this helps.

Comment: worked very well and is a little bit "nicer" then my attempt, thanks ^^